# Swift - invalid update of collection view - multiple data changes

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have problem with my collection view and reloading/inserting items. I have my items array in view controller which contains `UICollectionView`. I change content of items array in many places. Sometimes I insert new items and sometimes I must reload items again from database.

Not all the time but sometimes I get "classic" error when inserting new items:

> Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0. The number of
>   items contained in an existing section after the update (16) must be
>   equal to the number of items contained in that section before the
>   update (16), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from
>   that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
>   items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

I know meaning of this error but It's really hard to fix this because as I wrote I can get notifications and then I reload data immediately (get items from database and reload collection view) and it could happen when inserting new item and similar conflicts could happen.

So I am not sure what is best solution for this. Should I lock array and make it thread safe (but I think I edit it mostly in main thread) or should I somehow "lock" collection and when there is insert operation then there couldn't be changes to items or collection view couldn't be reloaded? Or is there other solution?

Bonus: Is it possible that app wouldn't crash when error above happens and just full reload collection view? Propably not but it could help a lot.

Comment: I faced the same problem when I tried to add a item in a UICollectionView with 0 items so I just reloaded the collectionview when the data arrives

Comment: @Libor Zapletal : Unfortunately collection view does not provide begin updates and end updates like tableView to perform batch update to data source. Instead it provides perform batch updates which in itself is a pain. The way UICollectionView evaluates changes when data source changes is also a pain, removing data from data source is honored first and then the data insert to data source. As a result if you remove 5 cells and and add two once it removes 5 cells first and tries to reload finds the inconsistency in data source and crashes. I don't think array being non thread safe is the only

Comment: culprit here. Even with NSFetchedResultsController you will run into this kind of issues quite frequently. Even am facing the same issue. One work around I came up with, I clear data source before making any changes, and call reloadData and finally update data source with all changes and call reloadData again :) Clearing and reloading ensures collection view will not messes it up with deleting and inserting rows calculation. I know its pain full but thats the only solution I know for now with array.